# jQuery Facebox Parent Element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the `src` attribute of an element in the parent window just before I trigger Facebox close.

I have tried:

```
window.parent.$("#elementID").attr("src", "no-image.png");
$("#elementID").attr("src", "no-image.png");
```

But these dont work and I couldnt find anything on the interweb.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Who owns the parent window - is it in the same domain as the child, and does it have jQuery included? For testing purposes, does calling `$("#elementID").attr("src", "no-image.png");` from the parent (rather than the child IFRAME), work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you opened FaceBox dialog containing an iFrame, put the following code into the head of parent.

```
function changeSrc() {
    $(document).bind('afterClose.facebox', function () {
        $("#elementID").attr("src", "no-image.png");
    });
}
```

Call this function from the iframe.

```
parent.changeSrc(); //like $(document).ready(function () { parent.changeSrc(); }.
```

Now, close Facebox.